# ErrorException Cannot redeclare class Concrete\Package\MolliePlugin\Controller in Concrete5 website

Tags: exception, concrete5, redeclare, mollie

I'm new here, so I hope I'm doing this right. I inherited a portfolio of websites and one is a Concrete5 website. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with Concrete5 and I directly start with a site with an issue :(.

When I go to https://www.example.nl/index.php/dashboard/extend/install I get the following error.

Whoops \ Exception \ ErrorException (E_COMPILE_ERROR)
Cannot redeclare class Concrete\Package\MolliePlugin\Controller

[Image of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCMoH.png)

I hope that someone can give me some guidence on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the issue when looking in cPanel: there was mollie_plugin and mollie_plugin_not_working. I guess that my predecessor had an issue and renamed the folder and added the extension again.